# Route OBS filtered audio to applications such as Zoom or Discord

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, obs-studio

I am trying to achieve this (apparently) easy task where I want the OBS filtered audio to be used as input for programs such as Zoom, Discord and similar.

On Windows I simply use Virtual Audio Cable and then set the monitoring output to be the virtual one which I can later use as input for other programs.

On Linux (Ubuntu) I am struggling quite a bit to achieve something similar. I believe it should be achievable with pulseaudio but I can't figure it out how to make it work. Does anyone how to do it? Thanks!